# Why am I getting an ExtraValueException from mongoalchemy?

Tags: python, mongodb

Here is my class:

```
class Presentation(db.Document):
    title = db.StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    author = db.StringField (required=True)
    pages = db.DocumentField(Page, required=False)
    tags = db.StringField(max_length=120, required=False)
    id = db.IntField(required=True)
    currentPage = db.IntField()
def __str__(self):
     return 'Title:%s author:%s  id:%d currentPage:%d' % ( self.title, self.author,self.id,self.currentPage)
```

When I use it from the mongo shell, everything seems fine:

> db.Presentation.find({id:2})

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e9cdddd0ad5c97ee6000000"), 
"author" : "admin", "currentPage" : 3, "id" : 2, 
"pages" : { "content" : "", "pagenum" : 0 }, "title" : "dd" }
```

but when I am using MongoAlchemy,

> > > p = query.filter(Presentation.id==2).first()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/mongoalchemy/query.py", line 136, in first
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/mongoalchemy/query.py", line 388, in next
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/mongoalchemy/document.py", line 318, in unwrap
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/mongoalchemy/document.py", line 152, in __init__

mongoalchemy.exceptions.ExtraValueException: currentPage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the [doc string of the exception](https://github.com/jeffjenkins/MongoAlchemy/blob/master/mongoalchemy/exceptions.py#L27) and It seems like for mongoalchemy the model defined doesn't register currentPage as an attribute of `Presentation` document, but in the code you copy pasted the class definition define the attribute.

If the class you copy pasted is the class that you defined in your project, try to delete .pyc files in your project and re-run the application.

By the way `currentPage` variable name does not follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Naming Conventions.

Comment: Thank you. Something was out of sync.  I ended up deleting the pyc files like you suggested and also cleaned the document via db.collection.remove() and <collection>.drop(). That seems to have fixed it. thanks also for pointing out the naming convention

Comment: when you try to fix something, you'd better do it step by step, like: 1) removing pyc 2) testing if it's not fixed try something else like cleaning the database. This way you have a better understanding of the tools you use and can prevent future errors.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else with a ExtraValueException, you can also see this error if you put an extra comma in the Class definition. For example if you had had:

```
...
pages = db.DocumentField(Page, required=False),
tags = db.StringField(max_length=120, required=False)
...
```

trying to use either pages or tags would give an ExtraValueException.

This I learnt to my own pain.